# Set NULL date in Oracle APEX mobile

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have the following form for my APEX app

[The user set dates on this form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePhmo.png)

On the computer version, the user can delete the date and leave the value NULL. But in the smartphone that doesn't happen. Is there an atribute or button I can set on APEX so that the user has the option to set a date NULL?

**Just for context:** this is a form to add a task, but an already added task can be put ON HOLD (not scheduled) to be dealt with later. That's why the user might want to take a task out of the schedule and plan it later.

Comment: I tested this in Chrome on my Android phone, a long press on the date item allows me to clear it out like any text item. Is your issue specific to any particular browser or device?

Comment: Hi, I am using Chrome but I "installed" the app as a PWA and this trick of pressing doesn't seem to work for me. I also tried directly on the browser and it doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any mobile applications, but - did you try one of the following:

- create a button which - when pressed - runs a **process** which sets

  ```
  :P1_START_DATE := NULL;
  ```
- create a button and its **dynamic action** that *Clears* the start date item
- enable **Quick picks** for the date item and set label-value pair to

  - Label: No start date
  - Value: leave it empty

Comment: I guess i'll have to create a button. I just didn't want to add more elements to the interface and was wondering if there was a way around it. But thanks